# Is there a single word for "not yet released because it is still being worked on"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am working on a quality assurance system where some procedures might be in a state where they haven't yet been released because they are currently being worked on. They may have also been a previous release of the document, and the document I am trying to describe is the one with changes to the previous release.

An analogy might be how you would refer to Mac OSX 10.8 Mountain Lion - it isn't yet released, because it is still being worked on.

I have been calling it `unreleased` but this to me sounds awkward and doesn't really describe the state.

Is there a word that I'm overlooking that describes this?

Comment: If it’s not done yet, it’s not done yet.

Comment: *the unreleased update*. I'm not sure there's a single word to describe what you want.

Comment: In my experience millions of words have been used to describe and/or obscure this situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that "the document I am trying to describe is the one with changes to the previous release" means "the document I am trying to describe makes changes relative to the current release and is its successor".

Consider terms like *next-generation, successor, in development, next-rev, pre-release, upcoming,* and *future* or *future version*.

Comment: Yes your assumption is correct. Thanks those words will all be helpful synonyms for me :)

Answer (score 2):

Not a single word, but ***in the works*** is a common phrase in such situations:

> being planned, worked on, or produced.

<sup>*[NOAD](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/work?region=us&q=in%20the%20works#work__52)*</sup>

Answer (score 2):

When talking of technical development, we mostly use **in the pipeline**.

> There is a new version, *Mountain Lion* in the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

"In/under-production/development."  Take your pick.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative would be *in-process*.

Answer (score 0):

**In progress** can be used for such cases.

> in progress: in session, currently being conducted, in the middle of, progressing.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are talking about a 'preliminary' version of the software, sometimes called an 'alpha' if it has a reasonable degree of functionality; a 'beta' usually means the features are frozen, but subject to change due to bug-fixing ( 'beta testers' are users who help find those bugs or provide feedback on small changes that might improve things ). The acronym 'WIP' ( for 'work in progress' ) is also sometimes used.

Answer (score 0):

A document which is not yet in its final form can be referred to as a [draft document](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/draft) or *at the draft stage*.

A new version of a previously released document can be a draft. For example: *The current version of the procedure is defined in 1.2.47; the major revision to the procedure will be defined in document 1.3 which is currently is in draft. 1.3 will take effect when it has been approved and released.*

Answer (score -2):

I believe "pending" would be an appropriate, single word describing the situation.

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.