# One word for "not yet activated"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm working on a page that shows a card that has not yet been activated, but I need something shorter to describe the card state. "Disabled" would not be applicable because the card can be in a disabled state. This applies to a new card that needs to be activated in order to start using it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Chandre, welcome to English Language & Usage! If you think you might use our site again (and I hope you do), please make sure you take the [Tour]. :-)

Comment: It's not exactly the same as what you're asking, but it might be worth looking at the answers to this question: [Is there a single word for “not yet released because it is still being worked on”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/66188).

Comment: Avoid asking questions that solicit multiple valid answers. Such questions may be closed. See: “[What types of questions should I avoid asking? - Help Center](/help/dont-ask)”. Avoid asking for help naming something. See: “[What topics can I ask about here? - Help Center](/help/on-topic)”. Such questions may be closed because they only help the person asking. Sometimes such a request can be salvaged by rewriting to help future visitors. Or, you can look for other naming resources: “[Help naming something – Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=help+naming+something)”.

Comment: @MetaEd See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's commonly called an "**unactivated** card," as against a "live card."

"[Enhancing Payment Card Security](https://abs.org.sg/consumer-banking/consumers/payment-card-security)," FAQs, ABS (The Association of Banks in Singapore)

> **(II) Introducing first-usage alert and activation procedure for new/replacement cards**
>   1. **What do I do when I receive the new chip card?**
>       To prevent unauthorised use of your new card should the card be intercepted or stolen in the mail, your bank will advise you whether you have been issued an "unactivated card" or a "live card":
>   a. "Unactivated Card" – you have to activate your card before use.
>   b. "Live Card" – no activation is required by you; a first usage alert may be sent to you via SMS, email or letter (on advice of your bank).

*See also*:
[Marqeta API, Cards](https://www.marqeta.com/api/docs/VhypzxwAANwA_Vgx/cards#create_card)
**Card state**
UNACTIVATED         The card has been created but is non-functional. This is the initial state of a card.

Answer (score 0):

Pending is suitable for language around billing and user account activation.

Comment: Hi Liam, welcome to English Language & Usage! This site is a bit different from other Q&A sites: a good answer is expected to be detailed, and explain why it is correct - preferably by quoting a reference or linking to a source (e.g. a dictionary definition). For more information, see [Answer], and for a great introduction to how EL&U works, I recommend taking the **[Tour]**. :-)